# Regex matches only one string. Need it to match two

Tags: python, regex

I have the following regex

```
^(.+?)(\s+engine$|\s+ROW_FORMAT)
```

with ignore case enabled.

The problem with this is, it matches either "engine" or "row_format" and doesn't match both (as shown in the [last example](https://regex101.com/r/qC3tB7/3)). What am I missing here?

```
In [17]: st = 'this is my engine and row_format'
In [18]: match = re.match('^(.+?)(\s+engine$|\s+ROW_FORMAT)', st, re.I)

In [19]: match
Out[19]: <_sre.SRE_Match at 0x26c5030>

In [20]: match.group(1)
Out[20]: 'this is my'

In [21]: st = 'this is my row_format and engine'

In [22]: match = re.match('^(.+?)(\s+engine$|\s+ROW_FORMAT)', st, re.I)

In [23]: match.group(1)
Out[23]: 'this is my'

In [24]: match.group(2)
Out[24]: ' row_format'

In [25]: match.group(3)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-da7df187e689> in <module>()
----> 1 match.group(3)

IndexError: no such group
```

Comment: Can you put your code?

Comment: add the special character `+`, which causes the resulting RE to match 1 or more repetitions of the preceding RE: `^(.+?)(\s+engine$|\s+ROW_FORMAT)+`

Comment: @FedericoPiazza The code is mostly in the link though I have added the output from repl.

Comment: @Hamms thanks that works.

Comment: @Hamms you should post your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add the special character `+`; this [causes the resulting RE to match 1 or more repetitions of the preceding RE](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)

```
^(.+?)(\s+engine$|\s+ROW_FORMAT)+
```